# Using Hilt @IntallIn for a dagger-2 module which has static provides method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

While doing a dagger-2 to hilt migration, got this error for a module

**Error:**

```
FooModule.Companion is listed as a module, but it is a companion
object class. 
Add @Module to the enclosing class 
and reference that instead.
```

**Before Hilt**

```
@Module
abstract class FooModule {

 @Binds
 @FooScope
 abstract fun bindsManager(impl: FooManagerImpl): FooManager
 
 @Module
 companion object {
     
   @Provides
   @FooScope 
   @JvmStatic
   fun providesConfig(prefs: SharedPreferences): FooConfig = FooConfigImpl(prefs) 
 }

}
```

**After Hilt**

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class FooModule {

 @Binds
 @FooScope
 abstract fun bindsManager(impl: FooManagerImpl): FooManager
 
 @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
 @Module
 companion object {
     
   @Provides
   @FooScope 
   @JvmStatic
   fun providesConfig(prefs: SharedPreferences): FooConfig = FooConfigImpl(prefs) 
 }

}
```

Migration doc reference: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-dagger-to-hilt#4

Comment: Got to know about Jake Wharton's comment on using `objects` instead https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-410041915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `companion object` to `object`

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class FooModule {

 @Binds
 @FooScope
 abstract fun bindsManager(impl: FooManagerImpl): FooManager
 
 @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
 @Module
 object AppModule{
     
   @Provides
   @FooScope 
   fun providesConfig(prefs: SharedPreferences): FooConfig = FooConfigImpl(prefs) 
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dagger 2.26](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.26) made it an error to include a companion object module in the `modules` parameter of `@Component` or `@Subcomponent`.  Instead, companion objects are automatically included if the containing class is a module.  Hilt's `@InstallIn` simply adds the annotated module to a generated component class, so you get the same error if you annotate a companion object with `@InstallIn`.

Remove `@InstallIn` (and `@Module`) from the companion object, and everything should work fine.